# Trigger jQuery animate.css function

Tags: jquery, animate.css

I'm not that experienced with jQuery and I'm having some difficulty triggering an animation from the animate.css library. I've got it to work using clicks, but not in the area I want.

Here's the function that works with clicking:

```
$(function() {
    var animation_name = 'animated shake';
    var animation_end = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

    $('#link-add').on('click',function() {
        $('#add-paypal').addClass(animation_name).one(animation_end,function() {
            $(this).removeClass(animation_name);
        });
    });
});
```

And here's where I want to make it work:

```
$('#add-link').on('change', function() {

    var animation_name = 'animated shake';
    var animation_end = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

    var link = $('#add-link').val();
    var paypal = $('#add-paypal').val();

    if (! paypal)
    {
        //Animate #add-paypal
    };
    else
    {
        //Animate #link-add
    };
});
```

Comment: Happy New Year by the way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`animate.css` provides css animation classes which are triggered when added to element so to trigger it you simply do

```
$('#add-paypal').addClass(animation_name);
```

but if you want to know when animation finished you can listen to event

```
$('#add-paypal').addClass(animation_name)
  .one(animation_end, function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass(animation_name);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to identify the element on which the animation is to be triggered on and parallelly keeping it simplified.

```
$('#add-link').on('change', function() {

    var animation_name = 'animated shake';
    var animation_end = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

    var link = $('#add-link').val();
    var paypal = $('#add-paypal').val();

    if (! paypal)
    {
        var el = paypal;
    };
    else
    {
        var el = link;
    };

    if(el)
        el.addClass(animation_name).one(animation_end,function() {
            $(this).removeClass(animation_name);
        });
});
```